# Open image in gallery with Android Nougat

Tags: android, image, save, android-7.0-nougat

I want to open a saved image in gallery on Android Nougat but what I get is a black gallery page with message "Can't load the photo".

That's my code:

**Manifest**

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Path generated in DrawView**

```
public static boolean save(Bitmap bitmap){
    Date now = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'_'HH:mm");

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "Crash");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        lastImagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Crash/" + simpleDateFormat.format(now) + ".jpg");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(lastImagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        fos = null;
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Open Image Listener**

```
    private class OpenImageListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + DrawView.getLastImagePath().getAbsolutePath()), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", DrawView.getLastImagePath());
            intent.setData(photoUri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I generate a wrong path for the image, but with old version it works (I tried on Marshmallow and works great).

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting ? File URI exposed? please check the log

Comment: `folder.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory in which case it returns false. If so do not continue but display a toast and return false.

Comment: What is the value returned by save()?

Comment: `lastImagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Crash/" + simpleDateFormat.format(now) + ".jpg");`. You are defining the folder again. That is not good coding. Change to `lastImagePath = new File(folder, simpleDateFormat.format(now) + ".jpg");`

Comment: I don't get any error, I just don't see the image in the gallery.
The save() function return true if image is saved correctly.

Comment: What is the actual value returned by save was the question. And please add the mkdirs code. Strange that you dont give the info asked or react to suggestions.

Comment: What is the file length?

Comment: The directory is created correctly

Comment: What do you mean by file length?

Comment: Files have length/size isnt it? What is returned by save()?

Comment: The file size depends on why the file is created at the time. Usually is about 100KB. save() return true if file is created correctly, false if there's any problem.

Comment: My god what is actually returned by save()? You dont have to explain the code. We want to know what happens.

Comment: I take a "screenshot" and I save it passing it to the save function. After, I show a snackbar and when the user click the Open button, he can see the saved image. With the save function I create the file and save it. If save return true i show the snackbar with the Open button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `else` block in `onClick()`, after calling `setData()` on your `Intent` to set the `Uri`, call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent`.

As it stands, the other app has no rights to work with the content identified by the `Uri`. Adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` does this.

This is covered in [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#Permissions), along with modern books on Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

I do expire the same issue with almost all apps I tried, my code is the same as yours and as far as the google docs say it looks to be correct...

The only *"solution"* I can offer you is to compile against version 23(https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html) to avoid the forced strict mode for file URIs.
Of course you also have to downgrade your Android support libs in case you are using them.

If someone has a better idea please share...

Answer (score 0):

To view image from mobile emulated gallery is no more difficult but in nougat is quite different i have run time image created and wants to see that image its failed many times but finally its run with this code

1.after a long struggle i write this code , dont forget to add, fil provider in mainfest file as you may know .

```
 MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(file.getName());
            String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
            if (type == null)
                type = "*/*";

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                // only for gingerbread and newer versions
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
                intent.setDataAndType(photoUri, type);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri data = Uri.fromFile(file);
                intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
```